# In C++17, why is pointer type deduction apparently inconsistent for class templates versus function templates?

Tags: c++, c++17, rvalue-reference, lvalue, perfect-forwarding

If I change CLASS in the code below to be 0 rather than 1, it will compile using either gcc or clang.  But if CLASS is 1, it will fail (on the second usage of bar) for both compilers.

```
#define CLASS 1

#include <utility>

void f(int *a);

template <typename Arg>
#if CLASS
struct bar {
#else
void
#endif

bar(Arg && arg) { f(std::forward<Arg>(arg)); }

#if CLASS
};
#endif

void foo()
{
  int dummy;
  int *p = &dummy;

  #if !CLASS
    #define a
    #define b
  #endif

  bar a(p + 0);
  bar b(p);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/g/3hpq2u

As two separate snippets, without conditional compilation:

Fails:

```
#include <utility>

void f(int *a);

template <typename Arg>
struct bar {    
    bar(Arg && arg) { f(std::forward<Arg>(arg)); }
};

void foo()
{
  int dummy;
  int *p = &dummy;

  bar a(p + 0);
  bar b(p);
}
```

Succeeds:

```
#include <utility>

void f(int *a);

template <typename Arg>
void bar(Arg && arg) { f(std::forward<Arg>(arg)); }

void foo()
{
  int dummy;
  int *p = &dummy;

  bar(p + 0);
  bar(p);
}
```

Comment: You should make two separete snippets, this is hardly readable...

Comment: OK, my bad, it's irrelevant whether 'p' has a pointer type or not.  The issues applies with any copyable type.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/g/gRDTCv

Answer (score 8):

```
template <typename Arg>
struct bar {
    bar(Arg && arg) { f(std::forward<Arg>(arg)); }
};
```

and

```
template <typename Arg>
void bar(Arg && arg) { f(std::forward<Arg>(arg)); }
```

Are not the same thing.  In the function `bar` you have a forwarding reference.  This allows you to accept a lvalue(`p`) or rvalue(`p + 0`).

With the struct `bar` you no longer have a forwarding reference.  The reason it is no longer a forwarding reference is because it is no longer a function template parameter.  `T&&` is only a forwarding reference when `T` is not known.  Since your `T` (`Args`) is known (well not really but it is being deduced so it can be known) that means it is no longer a forwarding reference.

That means you have a rvalue-reference to the class template type.  That works well for

```
bar a(p + 0);
```

since the result is a temporary `int*`(`int*&&`) but with

```
bar b(p);
```

you have a you have a `int*`(`int*&`) so you cannot bind the rvalue-reference to that.

---

If you want the class to behave like the function does you would need something like

```
struct bar {
    template <typename Arg>
    bar(Arg && arg) { f(std::forward<Arg>(arg)); }
};
```

otherwise if you just need to accept lvalues and rvalues you could just add overloads to handle that

```
template <typename Arg>
struct bar {
    bar(Arg & arg) { f(arg); }
    bar(Arg && arg) { f(std::move(arg)); }
};
```

Comment: Yes but can you explain why is it a "forwarding reference" in case of a template function but not so in case of a struct? What is the difference in the deduction process exactly?

Comment: You know, unary-plus is perfect for turning an lvalue into an rvalue: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0d595808fe20d91c

Comment: The problem with the work-around is that, for what I'm trying to do, I need a class template, not just a class with a templated constructor.  For example:  https://godbolt.org/g/otqkTe

Comment: Or you can write a user-defined deduction guide: `template<typename Arg> bar(const Arg&) -> bar<Arg&>;` and after that `bar(p);` will compile just fine.

Comment: @WaltK your snippet won't work, because if it were to deduce `int*&` for `Arg`, the member `Arg t;` would have to be initialized as a reference member. see https://godbolt.org/g/Lnudnt

Comment: I thought that, if you want an lvalue actual parameter to be deduced as having a reference type, you use std::ref.  Otherwise, it's deduced as having the dereferenced  type of the lvalue.

Comment: @gmoshkin I've added that to the answer

Comment: @WaltK What are you actually trying to accomplish?  I have added to the answer what I guess might be what you actually need.

Comment: The issue came up for this class (PostScript):  https://github.com/ywkaras/trafficserver/blob/XDebugFixes/lib/ts/PostScript.h

Comment: @WaltK As a work around you can just have the class take a callable then then when you construct it you can use a lambda to bind the arguments to the thing you actually want to call.  Something like this: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bce0a1386efc70d2

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you're trying to achieve here, but here are some ways to get to a working example. Given:

```
#include <utility>

void f(int *a);

template <typename Arg>
struct bar {    
    bar(Arg && arg) { f(std::forward<Arg>(arg)); }
};
```

You can initialize an object with an explicit template argument specification:

```
void foo()
{
  int dummy;
  int *p = &dummy;

  bar a(p + 0); // Arg is deduced to be int*
  bar<int*&> b(p); // Arg is explicitly int*&
}
```

Or you can provide a **user-defined deduction guide** for your template struct (see [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction)):

```
template<typename Arg> bar(const Arg&) -> bar<Arg&>;

void foo()
{
  int dummy;
  int *p = &dummy;

  bar a(p + 0); // Arg is deduced to be int*
  bar b(p); // Arg is deduced to be int*&
}
```

Keep in mind that if your struct has any members of template type and you want to be able to instatiate the struct with a reference type, those members would have to be initialized:

```
template <typename Arg>
struct bar {
    Arg member; // if Arg is int*& then member has type int*&
    bar(Arg && arg) : member(arg) { f(std::forward<Arg>(arg)); }
};
```

Or if you don't need the member to have a reference type you can do something like this:

```
template <typename Arg>
struct bar {
    std::remove_reference_t<Arg> member; // if Arg is int*& then member has type int*
    bar(Arg && arg) { f(std::forward<Arg>(arg)); }
};
```